# Adding disable to certain select options in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

A user can chose 5 options. Once they choose one, they can not choose it again. Currently, I simply remove previously used options from the list...so, they can only choose from previously unused ones.  The only thing I don't like about this is that as the user is adding a new record to the database, they might wonder why options seem to be missing from the list.

One idea I had was to leave previously used options in the list but cross them out and make them disabled.

Is it possible to disable (and/or add a class) to only certain options in a select?  Simple_form seems to have an option_html helper but, didn't see it documented.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out this is quite easy to do.  Rails supports it...

```
 <%=  f.association :ying, collection: @yangs, :disabled => @used_yangs %>
```

Comment: seems I should be able to style the disabled options using "option:disabled { color: red !important; }" ... but, this does not override the default browser style as expected.

Comment: this works for the input, but the wrapper doesn't get the `disabled` class, which makes it impossible to style the label when you use `as: :radio_buttons`

Comment: I tried the following: <%= f.association :attendee, collection:@attendees, label: false, prompt: 'Select your name', :input_html => { :class => "assoc"},:disabled =>@used_attendees  %>

But it does not work, any ideas?

Comment: Acrux - Your code looks correct...  Are you sure @used_attendees is returning the array of ids you expect?

Answer (score 5):

It works for me only when I pass ids into disabled option. Like this:

`= f.association :stuff, disabled: Stuff.where(enabled: false).map(&:id)`

Using Rails 4.2.3

It's correct regarding Rails docs. Check `:disabled` description here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

Comment: This was also the case for me (4.2.3 also